# URL manipulation

Tags: java

I want to do a little manipulation with URLs.

It is required to add a sub domain in already created URL like shown below

Inputs

```
String inputURL = "http://www.myhost.com";
String subdomain = "newlocation";
```

output

```
String output = "http://www.newlocation.myhost.com";
```

I was thinking if there is any existing utility class that can do this for me. expert can have something to say.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Paul Tomblin, +1 and it's a shame you don't get rep for that.

Comment: pointing out the rules of the site isn't exactly rep-deserving, but is a good thing in general.

Comment: was more the way it was said. I chuckled, then sighed.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What is the correct result for `http://www.sub1.sub2.myhost.com`? What about `http://myhost.com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that "www" is also subdomain. So you are actually appending another subdomain.

```
    String inputURL = "http://www.myhost.com";
    String subdomain = "newlocation";

    URL url = new URL(inputURL);

    String[] domainParts = url.getHost().split("\\.");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < domainParts.length; i ++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            sb.append(subdomain + ".");
        }
        sb.append(domainParts[i] + ".");
    }
    String query = "";
    String port = "";
    if (url.getQuery() != null) {
        query = "?" + url.getQuery();
    }
    if (url.getPort() != -1) {
        port = url.getPort() + "";
    }
    String output = url.getProtocol() + ":" + port + "//" + sb.toString() + "/" + url.getPath() + query;
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: +1 for using the URL class and not reinventing the URL parser wheel

Comment: That does not mean that I cannot be better (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093544/url-manipulation/2093990#2093990).  :-) Having to render is not nice and your code has a bug is will prints "http://www.newlocation.myhost.com./"

Comment: Yes that works for me.
But This code snippet works only with the URLs with "www". If my URL does not include "www", subdomain is added at position 1; as condition if for loop.
I am going to use this as my URL will always come with www including.

One more thing

    sb.append(domainParts[i] + ".");

you don't have to add "." in every sub-domain as it get added after that 'com' too. By the way i have changed that method and get it working.

Comment: yes, modify it as you need (and fix the dot-ending ;) ). It is just advising to use the URL class, as it supports the RFC

Answer (score 3):

It is sufficient to parse only the host part of the URL and use the URI to render.

```
URL url = new URL(inputURL);
String host = url.getHost().replaceAll("(([.][^.]+){2,2})$", "." + subdomain + "$1");
String newUrl = new URI(url.getProtocol(), host, url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
String output = inputURL.replaceAll("(http://[^.]+\\.)(.*)", "$1" + subdomain + ".$2");
```

Comment: Edited so it matches the first element of any URL, not just www.

Comment: I don't know what you have done Dean! But it is magical. Thanks your answer. I will learn this notations and will use in any other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) (Link to the Java API doc) and then you will probably need to use one of the `insert()` methods

Comment: well amit; 

This can do and i thought of this too. But i was looking some URL utility class for out of the box help.
Now think of a situation where there is no www in URL. So will you suggest me to check this as a special case? 
Sorry! No! I will not think of doing so. as long as there is no any other elegant option. :)

Comment: How elegant a solution are you looking for? Write a Java class yourself and put it up there for others to benefit and yours too. THAT will be elegant:)

Comment: Yes Amit; That will be good and I am already making my plan to do so.